# Normalization procedure behind haar transform in R

Tags: r, haar-wavelet, dwt, wavelet-transform

I run the haar transform for `[9,7,3,5]` (using wavelets package) and I'm not figuring out how to achieve the output coefficients. I believe that the unnormalized result would be: `[6,2,1,-1]`. From what I've read, the normalization is done by multiplying each coefficient by `2^(-j/2)`, but this shouldn't be the case.

```
library(wavelets)
wt <- dwt(c(9,7,3,5), filter="haar", boundary="periodic", fast=FALSE)
wt
```

Comment: Please show some code for what you did.

Comment: The code is the following:
wt <- dwt(c(9,7,3,5), filter="haar", boundary="periodic", fast=FALSE)
wt
The coefficients I get are 12,-4,1.41,-1.41.

Comment: Please compare your post with [how to post a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit accordingly, in its current state no user can reproduce your issue